# Creating a PhoneGap plugin with a static library

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a native SDK for both iOS and Android platforms and now a customer requested a JS SDK for PhoneGap. I've followed a simple tutorial in order to learn how to create a PhoneGap plugin and it's quite easy: [create PhoneGap Plugin tutorial](https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/entry/introduction_to_custom_cordova_plugin). But my problem is that I need to add a static library (.a file or .jar) as part of my plugin.

Checking out the plugin.xml specification I've found several tags for different kinds of files:

- resource-file
- header-file
- lib-file
- framework

I think that the correct choice is lib-file but the sample shows a dynamic library in BlackBerry:

`<lib-file src="src/BlackBerry10/native/device/libfoo.so" arch="device" />
<lib-file src="src/BlackBerry10/native/simulator/libfoo.so" arch="simulator" />`

Any clue? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add it like a source-file and specify that is a framework in order to add the library to the target:

`<source-file src="src/ios/YourSDK/YourAFile.a framework="true"`